# Get an observable into HTML

Tags: angular, observable

I want to show an observable in HTML, my code is not working.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<p *ngFor="let test of map | async">Hier kommt: {{test}}</p>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']})

export class AppComponent{
public sourceOne = of(4, 5, 6 );
public map = this.sourceOne.pipe(map(val => val * 10)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));}
```

Comment: You should use the `tap()` operator if you want to log the stream to the console. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues with your implementation.

You're subscribing to the Observable which will give you a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`.

Plus what you want to do is `map` the elements of an Array. The response that you'll get inside `map` would be an `Array` and not a number.

So inside that `map` Rxjs Operator, you'll have to use the `map` Operator of an Array as well.

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<p *ngFor="let test of map | async">Hier kommt: {{test}}</p>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  public sourceOne = of([4, 5, 6]);
  public map = this.sourceOne.pipe(map(res => res.map(num => num * 10)));
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-of-map?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.